# C/C++ Sockets HTTP Request: Connection reset by peer

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I'm trying write a C++ program that can make GET requests to a given URL with sockets to learn more about how HTTP works. I've coded up what I think is the basic structure of what I should be doing:

1. Create a socket
2. Connect the socket to host
3. Send request byte by byte
4. Received response byte by byte

I get this error most of the time when I'm reading the response from the server: `ERROR reading response from socket Connection reset by peer`. This is getting triggered by an if statement in the while loop where I'm reading the response when `read` returns -1. I'm using `SOCK_STREAM`.

How should I change the way I'm receiving the response/the type of socket I'm using to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is using Wireshark to make sure you're actually sending the right data

Comment: You need a space between the route and `HTTP/1.1`

Comment: There is a space, sorry it isn't clear in how I'm constructing it there but it gets added when I parse the route from the URL.

Comment: The GET requests always send correctly (don't return status 400), but the server usually closes the connection before I can finish receiving all of the data.

Comment: In that case please provide a [mre]

Comment: Done; I had trouble getting it working in an online C++ compiler, but there isn't that much code if you'd like to run it on your own machine. Thank you!

Comment: *"but the server usually closes the connection before I can finish receiving all of the data."* - How do you know where *"all of the data"* ends? There is nothing in your code which computes where the end of the response should be. See [this part in the standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) how to compute the expected length of the message body based on the information from the response header. And note that it might be much easier to use HTTP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1 since HTTP/1.0 is the simpler protocol.

Comment: As the code currently is it already fails for me when sending. This is because you are trying to send MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH bytes instead of only the length of `message`.

Comment: With the latest edit the question now contains no useful details to tackle the problem. There is no code to reproduce the problem. This might be even worse than the previous edit which had at least code even though this one failed with different problems than described.